# $L=\{v_1,...,v_k\}$ is linearly independent and doesn't span the space $V$ then there exists $v\in V$ such that $L \cup \{v\}$ is linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra

> let $V$ be a linear space , Prove that if $L=\{v_1,...,v_k\}$ is linearly independent subset of $V$  and does not span the space $V$ then there exists $v\in V$ such that $L \cup \{v\}$ is linearly independent

I want to know if there is a different way other than what I did :

I proved by contradiction , assume $L \cup \{v\}$ is linearly dependent then $L$ is the maximal linearly independent set and therefore $L$ is a basis for $V$ therefore it spans $V$ thus our assumption is not right and $L \cup \{v\}$ is independent

I am thinking if there is another way because this is too immediate and doesn't really rely on anything besides the basic definition.

appreciate any suggestions , hints or tips for another solution thank you!

Comment: I think you need to assume something more about $v$ to have a true theorem.

Comment: @311411 I solved it according to something in the textbook that says let $B \not= \{0\}$ a subset of a linear space $V$ then $B$ is a basis iff B is a maximal linear independent set in $V$ , Am i missing something?

Comment: It should be, ”…then there exists $v$ such that $L \cup \{v\}$ is linearly independent”. Then the question would be a standard one.

Comment: My concern is this example in V = 3-space. Let $L=\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0)\}$; it seems independent to me. What happens if now $v$ is $(1,1,0)\;\;$?

Comment: Now your title does not match your text

Comment: By the way, this is the statement that I initially thought you were after (before you edited): https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4104242/688046

Comment: @311411 appreciate the help , my mistake I translated it wrong :)

Comment: The title and the body of the question are totally different! "if $v\in V$..." is much stronger than $\exists v\in V$... Which question did you intend?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich edited , thank you.. I don't see a a reason to downvote the post though as I showed my way and just looking for a different way to learn more. and apologized as well as I translated it wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof idea is as follows: 
Since $L$ does not span $V$ it is true that $$V \backslash \text{span}(L) \neq \emptyset$$
That implies that there exists an element in $V$ that is not in the span of $L$ and thus cannot be written as a linear combination of the other elements in the span of $L$ which means there exists an element, call it $v$, in $V$ such that $L \cup \{v\}$ is linearly independent.

Comment: Thank you , why $$V \backslash \text{span}(L) \neq \emptyset$$ ? if it spanned $V$ then it would be equal to the empty set?

Comment: Exactly, that a set of vectors, call it $L$, spans $V$ means: span$(L)=V$. But the premise explicitely states that $L$ does not span $V$. So, that implies span$(L) \neq V$ and span$(L) \subseteq V$ as a span cannot be a supset of the vector space it lives in. With that it is true that $V \backslash$span$(L) \neq \emptyset$.